# Xmpp connection in service gets closed when its process is finished

Tags: android, service, process, xmpp, asmack

I am developing a android chat app.I have an activity and a service in the app.Here the service contains all the connection function and the communication between the activity and service is done using a binder.My service is running in background but the connection gets closed automatically when the process is finished after some time i see that in setting menu in the emulator.I have seen two options two overcome this first is to run service in a separate process which i am trying to avoid for now.Another is to run connection in a separate thread but i need some one to help me here as i am unable to do so.Here is my code

### Service.java

```
    public class MainService extends Service{
private XMPPConnection connection;
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.d("service","started");
new Connect().execute("");
return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVICE,PORT);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
    try {
        connection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                + connection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
    try {
        // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
        connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        setConnection(connection);
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "--------------------------------------");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "User: " + entry.getUser());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
        



        "Name: " + entry.getName());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "Type: " + entry.getType());
            Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                    .getUser());

            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                    + entryPresence.getStatus());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                    + entryPresence.getType());
            Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
            if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                    + entryPresence);

        }
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                + USERNAME);
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
    return null;       
}}

    public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
this.connection = connection;
if (connection != null) {
    // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
    PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
    connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                        .getFrom());
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody()
                        + " from " + fromName );
            }
        }
    }, filter);
}
    }

   public class MyBinder extends Binder 
    {
        MainService getService() {
        return MainService.this;
      }
      }

    public XMPPConnection getconnection()
    {
if (connection != null) {
    Log.d("MainService","connection send");
    return connection;  
}
else
{
    Log.d("MainService","connection null");
return null;    
}
```

}
}

### Main Activity

```
    public class XMPPChatDemoActivity extends Activity {
private MainService service;
private XMPPConnection connection;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if(!isMyServiceRunning())  
    {
    startService(new Intent(this,MainService.class));
    }
    }
 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, MainService.class), mConnection,
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    unbindService(mConnection);
    super.onPause();
  }
     private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
          service = ((MainService.MyBinder) binder).getService();
          Log.d("Service","Connected");
          Toast.makeText(XMPPChatDemoActivity.this, "Connected",                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
            connection=service.getconnection();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            connection=null;
            service = null;
        }
      };
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MainService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of you mentioned seemingly solution don't approach the issue: Android kills services when its resources are getting low. Typically you can fix this by either

1. Marking the service as foreground **(In this case not recommended<sup>1</sup>)**
2. Marking the service as `STICKY` so that it get's restarted after it got killed

I really recommend using the `STICKY` approach. Running a service with foreground activity ,au be simpler, because you simply have to add only one line of extra code, but it also prevents Android from releasing resources that are urgently needed somewhere else. If you service runs as foreground and suffers form memory-leaks or has for some other reason high memory usage, the device will become slow and Android is unable to fix this situation.

Therefore the best approach is to mark your service as `STICKY` and restore it's state once it got restarted. All good Android XMPP clients do that.

<sup>1: Foreground services are intended for services where a restart would result in a bad user experience, e.g. if the music player service gets restarted, the user will notice it. That's the typical example where marking a service as foreground is appropriate.</sup>

Comment: My service is already marked as sticky you can see that in the service code onstartcommand return value is sticky.My service is running in background and can receive incoming message but when the corresponding process gets closed the connection becomes null and i am not able to receive message.I have read your earlier answers where you told to create a new thread as service does not have any process associated with it so i have created async task but its still not helping.....

Comment: A thread has **always** a process associated with it. I may have said that the Android service which maintains the connection instance should be run/use a looper, in an extra thread so that the UI thread won't block if it's doing any work. **The best solution is to recreate the state after the service has been killed and restarted, this includes reestablishing the XMPP connection.** And that is what every good Android XMPP client does.